# How to update exif of ALAsset without changing the image?

Tags: ios, metadata, photo, exif, alasset

I use `setImageData:metadata:completionBlock:` of `ALAsset` to update the exif(metadata) of an asset.

I just want to update the metadata, but this method require an `imageData` as the first parameter. I use the code below to generate `imageData`, but it modified my image(I checked the file size and file hash).

```
ALAssetRepresentation *dr = asset.defaultRepresentation;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:dr.fullResolutionImage scale:dr.scale orientation:dr.orientation];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
```

Is there any other method I could use to update just the exif of an `ALAsset`? Or any way to generate the right `imageData` for method `setImageData:metadata:completionBlock:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to generate `imageData`. Code below:

```
Byte *buffer = (Byte *)malloc(dr.size);
NSUInteger k = [dr getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:dr.size error:nil];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:k freeWhenDone:YES];
```

So I can use the data above with `setImageData:metadata:completionBlock:` to update only the exif of `ALAsset`.

Comment: Could someone explain what this does? How does this not update the image?

Comment: @akaru, the above code gets the raw image data before it becomes a CGImage.  When writing via `setImageData:...`, the image is unmodified.